# Ícone de notificação push - OneSignal

Tags: icons, api

Eu estou utilizando o OneSignal para enviar notificações push para um aplicativo em Cordova que estou desenvolvendo.

As notificações são enviadas corretamente, porém não estou conseguindo alterar o ícone da notificação. Fica apenas um ícone de um "sino" que é padrão do OneSignal.

Eu segui a documentação oficial para personalização do ícone (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons) e mesmo assim não deu certo, criando os ícones nas pastas:

```
project-root/platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png (24x24)
project-root/platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png (36x36)
project-root/platforms/android/res/drawable-xdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png (48x48)
project-root/platforms/android/res/drawable-xxdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png (72x72)
project-root/platforms/android/res/drawable-xxxdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png (96x96)
```

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Depois de 1 semana muito longa consegui resolver esse empasse do ONESIGNAL

**1º Esqueça o método do site do IONIC, o código te um furo nesse IF**

```
if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir))
```

O fs.existsSync(destdir) retorna false, pois a pasta não existe na pasta raíz (/). Para ver o erro é só inserir alguns console.log no código e analisar o que está sendo feito.

**2º** Tome como base a instalação do IONIC Cloud Build dentro da documentação do Onesignal para alteração do ícone padrão ([link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons))

**3º** Entenda como funciona o RESOURCE-FILE do config.xml, que pertence a arquitetura do APACHE CORDOVA
(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file)

**4º** Após você gerar a pasta de ícones com os nomes corretos e guardá-las dentro do seu projeto em alguma pasta específica e entender todos os passo anteriores, você pode colar esse código no seu CONFIG.XML

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
```

*Conclusão*: pelo que eu entendi houve uma mudança na arquitetura de geração de arquivos res/ dentro da plataforma do IONIC, assim gerando um desacordo entre as documentações. E também, podemos concluir que, o IONIC tem uma parcela de culpa pois o código tipo HOOK dentro da documentação não funciona na versão v1. (não sei se também buga no v1 e v3)

Answer (score 0):

Também passei pelo mesmo problema, assisti e li vários materiais na internet que parecia fica cada vez mais complicado, e não é. 
Bom, eu usei o programa Paint 3D, mas pode usar outros também desde dê para alterar a imagem. 
É o seguinte. **Preencha o ícone todo de branco e deixe com o fundo transparente.**

-Selecione a imagem que você deseja colocar como ícone.

-Abra com o Paint 3D.

-Use a Seleção Mágica para corta a imagem, seja cauteloso pois e essa corte que vai definir a forma do seu ícone.
  -Depois de feito o corte vá em >Tela, e marque a opção "Tela transparente".

-Selecione o recorte e arraste para fora da imagem, em seguida passe a borracha no fundo da imagem deixando toda transparente.

-Depois de deixa o fundo da imagem todo transparente, arraste seu recorte novamente para dentro da imagem, e preencha ele todo de branco.

-Quando terminar de preencher vai ver que ja criou seu ícone, agora e so ajustar.

*recorte a imagem em formato quadrado, o ideal e 72px 72px.

*Verifique se não ficou bordas muitos grandes, pois isso afeta o tamanho do ícone.

-Agora salve a imagem, formato JPG OU PNG.

Agora teste, crie uma notificação de teste e coloque o seu ícone em "Badge" (Distintivo).

Veja como ficou seu ícone.

OBS: Dependendo do versão do seu Android e do Chrome não irá aparecer o ícone, mantenha os dois atualizados.

Então e isso, espero ter ajudado.